# Why geopandas changed polygon data type into str when using sjoin function?

Tags: python, geopandas

When I use the geopandas sjoin fnction, I find that my raw data type "shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon" changed into "str". Here is my code:

```
data=gdf.copy()
print(type(gdf['geometry'].iloc[1]))
df=pd.read_csv('/Users/apple/Documents/Phone/day_night.csv')
phone = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df.lon,df.lat),crs='EPSG:4326')
joined = gpd.sjoin(phone, gdf, how='right')
print(type(gdf['geometry'].iloc[1]))
print(type(data['geometry'].iloc[1]))
```

And my output is:

```
<class 'shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon'>
```

Does anyone know what is wrong?
Thanks a lot.